# Another question about morphisms, irreducibility and smoothness of varietes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$. Let $f^{\ast} = z^d f(x/z,y/z) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$. Let $U_z:=\{[x:y:z] \in \mathbb{P}^2\,:\, z \neq 0\}$. We know that $\varphi: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow U_z$, defined by $\varphi(x,y) = [x:y:1]$,  is an isomorphism. Let $X:= V(f) \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ and $Y:= V(f^{\ast}) \subset \mathbb{P}^2$.

**Q1.** Is it true that $\varphi$, restricted to $X$, defines an isomoprhism from $X$ to $Y \cap U_z$ whose inverse is defined by $\varphi^{-1}$, restricted to $U_z \cap Y$?

I am pretty sure that the map $\varphi$, defines at least a bijection from $X$ to $U_z \cap Y$. But do the maps $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ remain regular, when restricting their domain and target in this way? They do remain continuous but will regular functions on $Y\cap U_z$ still be pulled pack to regular functions on $X$ and vice versa?

**Q2**. Supposing that Q1 has an affirmative answer, it follows that $Y$ is irreducible, becuase $Y \cap U_z$ is irreducible and dense in $Y$ and the closure of an irreducible space is irreducible, isn't it?

**Q3**. If $X$ is nonsingular, does it follow that $Y$ is nonsingular?

Comment: What is your definition of regular function?

Comment: A function is regular, if locally it can be expressed as a ratio of two polynomials. (homogeneous of the same degree in the case of projective varieties)

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct and 3 is false. For 3, as a simple example, take $f=y-x^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to point out that the answer to A3 is no. Take the affine $y=x^3$. This is non singular. Its projectivisation is $f=x^3-z^2y=0$.
Now
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-z^2$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=-2zy$$ Now a singular point has all quantities zero this happens only at $[0,1,0]$ thus there is a singular point (a cusp) on the line at infinity.